# D3 Dynamic Height with Expandable SVG in SF Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, d3

I have a LWC that has an svg embedded inside of it. The SVG is a D3js tree grid that I can select parent nodes and the children will appear below it. The issue that I am having is that when I embed the component into the lightning app builder page layout, I am limited by the size that I can set the component to. I know that there is a workaround that I could make the svg size really big and have it scroll, but I don't necessarily know the full size of the component if I expand every possible parent node. And if all the nodes are closed, I don't want the user to have a scroll bar with a bunch of whitespace. Is there a way that I can override the Lightning App Builder sizing, so that however long the SVG becomes, the component grows to continue to make it visible to the user? Thanks!

**Update:**

This is essentially the component I am building. https://blockbuilder.org/mbostock/1093025 Unlike a static SVG, this one with the expanding/collapsing of the different elements changes the height differing amounts. So I essentially need a way of figuring out the height as I expand and collapse the different nodes.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but App Builder can respond to the height of your component's content.  I'm not experienced with D3js, but I'm going to venture a guess that there is some kind of communication breakdown between the SVG and the component's top-level template about what height it has.

Here's an example of a component with a variable-height SVG: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/z0Yi9F2Ba/1/edit

You can install it in a Trailhead playground and and play with the height via the config property in App Builder (must be on the home tab).

Comment: @MatthewSouther Maybe this will help. This is essentially the component I am building. https://blockbuilder.org/mbostock/1093025 Unlike a static SVG, this one with the expanding/collapsing of the different elements changes the height differing amounts. So I essentially need a way of figuring out the height as I expand and collapse the different nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't have much to do with Lightning App Builder -- it has more to do with D3 internals and understanding how to manage the value of the SVG's `height` attribute in LWC.

For a working LWC + D3 starting point, I played around with [the D3 example in lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsD3/libsD3.html) to see if I could get the component to adjust its height automatically.  I was able to make it work with the following steps:

1. Add the `@track` decorator to `svgHeight` so changes to its value force the DOM to rerender.
2. At the start of the `initializeD3()` method, declare `const cmp = this;`.  This allows you to update the main class's `svgHeight` property inside any of the D3 callback functions via the `cmp` variable.
3. Do some console logging to determine which callback functions are the last to execute when the user interacts with the SVG.  In this example it was the `ticked()` function.
4. Add the following lines at the end of `ticked()` or whatever function(s) you think are going to be most closely associated with the SVG resizing:

```js
// Update the height of the SVG (remember, cmp was defined in step 2 above)
cmp.svgHeight = svg.node().getBBox().height;

// Vertically re-center the SVG (may or may not be needed in your tree grid example)
simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, cmp.svgHeight / 2));
```

The alignment of the graphic elements inside the SVG wasn't perfect in this example, but could probably be improved by someone with a deeper knowledge of D3.  Bottom line: the component continually adjusted its height on the Lightning Page as I was interacting with it.

If interested, you can refer to [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990857/d3-js-how-to-get-the-computed-width-and-height-for-an-arbitrary-element/21991405) for background on how I came up with the `getBBox()` solution.

Comment: I'm getting the error of [Cannot read property 'force' of undefined]. I made sure that the height and width within the simulation line has valid values which is does. I tried logging the result of the d3.forceCenter function, and it returns another function. Is there something that I'm missing? It seems so close, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Blockbuilder example doesn't have a `simulation` variable like the lwc-recipes example.  Not sure that part is needed since a tree grid would probably stay vertically aligned at the top anyway.  Have you tried removing that line and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yeah, realized that as well after posting. Removed it and it's working for the most part, except for some tweaks that I need to make. Thank you so much!

Comment: one last question. The last function that I am trying to add the snippet of code to set the svg height is a toggle function. So as a result I am getting the expanded svg height when its collapsing and the collapsed svg height when its expanding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set `svgHeight` at the end of the function?  If so, there may be some async process at play, and you may need to play with `.then()`, async/await, or if worse comes to worst, `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I needed to have the height determination function near the start of the function that was getting called last. I also needed to wrap it in a Math.max() to get the greatest either from the getBBox() or from the calculation determining the size of all the rectangle elements holding the different values (nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom). Once I did that it worked perfectly! Thank you for the help!